# I am making a computer vision code with python and i got stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

everytime i try to run the code i get the following -->

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

[image: Thats the part where i keep getting the error from]

I tried moving the "`def hands():`" and the error just keeps occurring

Comment: It's an Indentation Error!!!! hands() method has no function body. Select from line 6 to line 21 and hit the tab, that should resolve your issue. make sure that ```hands``` you are using many time compiler may get confuse use proper name convention

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've closed your question since there's an existing one that covers this topic. In the future, please start with your own research. Just googling the error message should get you useful results. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: And [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent one time `cap` variable and all code that you what to be executed when calling `hands`.